# How to create multi-line chart with duplicate index categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

I have a DataFrame(df) in the below format. I want to create multi-line chart using this data.

```
Name    Category    Score   Count
A   Books   12025.4375  48
A   Music   17893.25    4
A   Movie   31796.37838 37
A   Script  1560.4  5
A   Art 973.125 8
B   Music   1929    15
B   Movie   3044.229167 48
B   Script  3402.4  10
B   Art 2450.125    8
C   Books   14469.3 10
C   Music   10488.78947 57
C   Movie   1827.101695 59
C   Script  7077    2
```

**Expected Output:**

I want unique Category at X-Axis.
Score at Y-Axis and Multiple lines representing multiple Name.

Count is just an additional data which is not needed for this graph.

I tried using the below syntax, which is not showing the output in expected format.

```
lines = df.line(x= 'Category',\
    y=['Name','Score'],figsize=(20,10))
```

I tried multiple options and answers available here but seems like nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) data and then plot by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), `line` is default value so should be omitted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = df.pivot('Category','Name','Score')
df1.plot(figsize=(20,10))
#show values in x axis
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df1.index)), df1.index)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect, Can you please suggest what should be the good visualization if i want to compare the score of each person in different categories. I have around 50-60 users with 10-15 categories.

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal - hmmm, there is a lot of users, so not sure if graph should be nice. Possible solution is create smaller groups for users if possible categorize some way and then plot.